# "Infinite Scrolling" in a ListView / Avoiding Re-entrant Scroll Events

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, event-handling, scrollviewer

My goal is to simulate "infinite scrolling" in a WPF `ListView`. I have achieved this task with some less-than-ideal methods, and I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

by "infinite scrolling" I mean the following:

Let's say a `ListView` has 20 items (ordered `1, 2, 3, 4, ... 17, 18, 19, 20`). When the user scrolls down one item, the item at the top of the `ListView` is removed and placed at the end of the `ListView` so the order of the items is `2, 3, 4, 5, ... 18, 19, 20, 1`. Now if the user scrolls down two items, the top two items are removed and placed at the end so the order of the items is `4, 5, 6, 7, ... 20, 1, 2, 3`. Now, similarly, if the user scrolls up one item, the item at the bottom of the `ListView` is removed and placed at the beginning so the order of the items is `3, 4, 5, 6, ... 19, 20, 1, 2`.

I have achieved this task with the following function assigned to the `ScrollChanged` event of the `ScrollViewer` I wish to be "infinite":

```
// sv - the ScrollViewer to which this event handler is listening
// lv - the ListView associated with "sv"
bool handle_scroll = true;
private void inf_scroll(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (handle_scroll) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.VerticalChange; i++) {
            object tmp = lv.Items[0];
            lv.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            lv.Items.Add(tmp);
            handle_scroll = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i > e.VerticalChange; i--) {
            object tmp = lv.Items[lv.Items.Count - 1];
            lv.Items.RemoveAt(lv.Items.Count - 1);
            lv.Items.Insert(0, tmp);
            handle_scroll = false;
        }
        if(!handle_scroll){
            sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset - e.VerticalChange);
        }
    }
    else {
        handle_scroll = true;
    }
}
```

Notice the variable `handle_scroll`. I put this in place because the call to `sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset` will cause the entire `inf_scroll` function to be called recursively if it was not there.

I **know** it is bad practice to scroll the `ScrollViewer` in a `ScrollChanged` event handler, so that's why I'm asking: is there a better way to do this? How can I prevent the recursive calls to `inf_scroll`? Is there a better way to simulate "infinite scrolling"?

Comment: What if the user scrolls up? It removes the last items and add to the begining or it doesn't modify the list?

Comment: @Magnetron Scrolling up should remove the last item and add it to the beginning. I edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it does not explicitly avoid scrolling in the `ScrollChanged` handler, you could try the following:

```
// sv - the ScrollViewer to which this event handler is listening
// lv - the ListView associated with "sv"
private void inf_scroll(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < e.VerticalChange; i++) {
        object tmp = lv.Items[0];
        lv.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        lv.Items.Add(tmp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i > e.VerticalChange; i--) {
        object tmp = lv.Items[lv.Items.Count - 1];
        lv.Items.RemoveAt(lv.Items.Count - 1);
        lv.Items.Insert(0, tmp);
    }
    lv.ScrollChanged -= inf_scroll;        // remove the handler temporarily
    sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.VerticalOffset - e.VerticalChange);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new Action(() =>{
        sv.ScrollChanged += inf_scroll;    // add the handler back after the scrolling has occurred to avoid recursive scrolling
    }));
}
```